# Select data from two different column of two different table and insert into one table in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to select uid from Table1(user_info) when username="somevalue" and select wid from Table2(week) when start_date="somedate" And insert it into Table3(timesheet) column uid and wid respectively. Your help would be much appreciable. Thanks

```
   <?php
    include "login.php";

    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldn't Connect");
    mysql_select_db("user_login") or die ("Couldn't Find Database"); 
    // set current date
    $startdate = $_GET["startDate"];
    $enddate = $_GET["endDate"];
    $mon=$_GET["mon"];
    $tue=$_GET["tue"];
    $wed=$_GET["wed"];
    $thur=$_GET["thur"];
    $fri=$_GET["fri"];
    $sat=$_GET["sat"];
    $sun=$_GET["sun"];
    $totalhour= $mon+$tue+$wed+$thur+$fri+$sat+$sun ;
    $insert_uid= "Insert into timesheet(uid) select uid from user_info where username=".$_SESSION['user']."";
    $result1= mysql_query($insert_uid);
    $insert_wid=  "insert into timesheet(wid) select wid from week where start_date= '$startdate'" ;
    $result2= mysql_query($insert_wid);

    $sql= "insert into timesheet(uid,wid,mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun,totalhour) values('$result1','$result2','$mon','$tue','$wed','$thur','$fri','$sat','$sun',$totalhour)";
    mysql_query($sql);
    echo $sql;
      echo "<h2>Thanks! You Timesheet submitted successfully</h2>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated. Use mysqli or pdo instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Use mysqli_ instead of mysql_

You're using mysql_ functions, you should use mysqli_, like this:

```
<?php
    include "login.php";

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","user_login");
    if(!$connect){die("Couldn't Connect");}
    // set current date
    $startdate = $_GET["startDate"];
    $enddate = $_GET["endDate"];
    $mon=$_GET["mon"];
    $tue=$_GET["tue"];
    $wed=$_GET["wed"];
    $thur=$_GET["thur"];
    $fri=$_GET["fri"];
    $sat=$_GET["sat"];
    $sun=$_GET["sun"];
    $totalhour= $mon+$tue+$wed+$thur+$fri+$sat+$sun ;
    $insert_uid= "Insert into timesheet(uid) select uid from user_info where username=".$_SESSION['user']."";
    $result1= mysqli_query($connect,$insert_uid);
    $insert_wid=  "insert into timesheet(wid) select wid from week where start_date= '$startdate'" ;
    $result2= mysqli_query($connect,$insert_wid);

    $sql= "insert into timesheet(uid,wid,mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun,totalhour) values('$result1','$result2','$mon','$tue','$wed','$thur','$fri','$sat','$sun',$totalhour)";
    mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    echo $sql;
      echo "<h2>Thanks! You Timesheet submitted successfully</h2>";
    ?>
```

### Selecting uid from user_info

```
$select1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT uid FROM user_info WHERE username='somevalue'"));
$uid = $select1['uid']; //assuming that you expect just one result from this query
```

### Selecting wid from week

```
   $select2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT wid FROM week WHERE start_date=''"));
   $wid = $select2['wid']; //assuming that you expect just one result
```

### Inserting into database

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO timesheet(uid,wid) VALUES('".$uid."','".$wid."')");
```